# xcodebuild throws "Unable to mount developer disk image" warning even when building against a generic device

Tags: xcodebuild

Running the command `xcodebuild -scheme "SchemeName" -configuration Release -derivedDataPath build/DerivedData -destination generic/platform=iOS clean build` throws this warning:

```
2018-03-28 18:18:44.282 xcodebuild[865:1393851]  iPhoneConnect: ## Unable to mount developer disk image, (Error Domain=com.apple.dtdevicekit Code=601 "Could not locate device support files." UserInfo={DeviceType=iPhone9,3, 
NSLocalizedDescription=Could not locate device support files., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=This iPhone 7 (Model 1660, 1778, 1779, 1780) is running iOS 11.3 (15E5216a), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.}) {
    DeviceType = "iPhone9,3";
    NSLocalizedDescription = "Could not locate device support files.";
    NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion = "This iPhone 7 (Model 1660, 1778, 1779, 1780) is running iOS 11.3 (15E5216a), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.";
}
```

even though I'm clearly building against a generic device, and not for the connected iPhone 7 device.

How can I disable these warnings?